# shinyapps.io- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have an app that I've uploaded to shinyapps.io, and I've been noticing some instability that I can't trace.  The app has a bunch of different reactive inputs which call code to filter, calculate, and plot some data.  Occasionally, a certain sequence of selecting these inputs causes the site to freeze and trigger a 500 Internal Server Error.

Strangely enough, when I execute the same commands on a locally-hosted (thru R) version of the app, I don't get an error.

It's a really booger to trace: any suggestions on what may be causing the problem and/or how to debug it better? I'm a javascript novice, so any help would be appreciated.

Full representative error log:

```
/opt/shiny-server/scripts/shiny-run: line 3:    32 Killed    
/bin/bash --login -c   "$SHINY_EXEC_COMMAND $SHINY_R_PATH $*"

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 
<<site@shinyapps.io>>/shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 
<<site@shinyapps.io>>/shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 
<<site@shinyapps.io>>/shared/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 
<<site@shinyapps.io>>/shared/datatables/css/DT_bootstrap.css
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright-- it turns out the problem is actually very simple.  The app was simply running out of memory.

In the error log, there was a line about processes being killed, which is indicative of not enough memory.  You can access the error log with 
    ShinyApps::showLogs()

To fix the problem, you can bump up the memory available to the app with: 
    shinyapps::configureApp("APPNAME", size="xlarge")

where "APPNAME" is the name of the app.  More info about memory is here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/shinyapps.html

Thanks to the folks at RStudio for helping diagnose.